# NoSuchElementException for Java File Scanner

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

Okay so I need to make a program that inputs a text file with a username and password. I'm using the Scanner and File objects to read from the file. Each line of users.txt contains a username and a password.

users.txt

username            password

```
 String fileName = "users.txt";
 try{
            File inFile = new File(fileName);
            Scanner fin = new Scanner(inFile);
            while(fin.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.print(fin.next());
            }
            fin.close(); 
   }
   catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
```

That code will output the username just fine but then after the textfile I get a  "NoSuchElementException".   as a result of the catch. Any reason why? The data is processed fine so why would I get a no such element exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each line has both user name and password, you should probably do something like this :

```
       while(fin.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.print(fin.next()); // username
            System.out.print(fin.next()); // password
            fin.nextLine(); // consume end of line
        }
```

or

```
       String line = null;
       while((line = fin.nextLine()) != null){
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            if (tokens.length > 1) {
                System.out.print(tokens[0]); // username
                System.out.print(tokens[1]); // password
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay so I was totally confused by the explanation by my programming professor about how the Scanner object methods work. I totally forgot about toString methods. Is that how that works? nextLine goes to the next line if it's not asking to be printed and prints the result if a print is requested? Thank you and for whatever reason your other code section didn't work.

Comment: @user2398026 Which one didn't work? Whether or not you print the output of the scanner makes no difference. Your problem was that hasNextLine would return true even if all that's available is the end of line character of the last line, in which case fin.next() would throw an exception.